# Recapcha V3 doesnt work on page with multiple forms

Tags: javascript, recaptcha-v3

i have an issue with Google Recaptcha V3. Id does work on single form but works only for first form if in page are more than 1 form.
How to make it work for all forms?
I know that issue is with  `id="recaptchaResponse"` but i have no ideas how to fix this! There are smilar questions ou there but could not found a solution.

Javascript:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=key1"></script>
<script>
    grecaptcha.ready(function () {
        grecaptcha.execute('key2', { action: 'contact' }).then(function (token) {
            var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
            recaptchaResponse.value = token;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Forms:

```
<form class="user" action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="source" value="form1">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit 1</button>

    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">
</form>

<form class="user" action="" method="post" name="form2" id="form2">
    <input type="hidden" name="source" value="form2">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit 2</button>

    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">
</form>
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem seems to be because the `getElementById` call only resolves the `recaptcha_response` input element in the first form and not the second.

A simple fix would be to change the ids of the `recaptcha_response` elements in each form to something different, say `recaptchaResponse1` and `recaptchaResponse2`. Then the Javascript code to set the tokens could be:

```js
grecaptcha.ready(function () {
  grecaptcha.execute('key2', { action: 'contact' }).then(function (token) {
    document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse1').value = token;
    document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse2').value = token;
  });
});
```

A better approach that is easier to maintain and will work for any number of forms is to specify a class name for the `recaptcha_reponse` inputs and use the `querySelectorAll` function to get all the inputs with the given class name and update them.

```html
<form class="user" action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="source" value="form1">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit 1</button>

    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" class="recaptchaResponse">
</form>

<form class="user" action="" method="post" name="form2" id="form2">
    <input type="hidden" name="source" value="form2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit 2</button>

    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" class="recaptchaResponse">
</form>
```

```js
grecaptcha
  .execute("key", {
    action: "contact"
  })
  .then(function(token) {
    document
      .querySelectorAll(".recaptchaResponse")
      .forEach(elem => (elem.value = token))
    ;
  });
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the id tag and use only name tag.

```js
grecaptcha.ready(function () {
    grecaptcha.execute({publicKey}, {action: 'forms'}).then(function (token) {
        var recaptchaElements = document.getElementsByName('recaptcha');
        for (var i = 0; i < recaptchaElements.length; i++) {
            recaptchaElements[i].value = token;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this answear! Will test it!